# get distinct field in hive query

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to query a table and de-dupe the query results

```
select distinct(id), distinct(name), distinct(date)
from table
where data_date = '20180722'
and active = True
group by market, country
order by userrole
```

What I want this to do is give me a list of distinct id, name, date etc. which is the first row from each of the grouped market, country groups, which are first sorted by userrole. Is there a way to do this in `hive`?

in `R` this would be:

```
df %>%
    select(id, name, date) %>%
    group_by(market, country) %>%
    arrange(userrole) %>%
    slice(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distinct` in SQL and HiveQL isn't a function, but a *keyword*. Specifying `distinct` once per query will give you distinct results, like `select distinct col1,col2...`.

You can use `row_number` function to achieve this.

```
select id,name,date
from (select t.*,row_number() over(partition by market,country order by userrole) as rnum
      from tbl t
     ) t
where rnum=1
```

Comment: are you using the same query for sure?

Comment: that worked! I had to add a few things to it and realized I was doing it a bit wrong. Thank you!

Comment: how come you don't have to alias the select portion to be `t.id, t.name, t.date`, and `t.rnum=1`? that always threw me off. I thought you were aliasing the subtable to be called `"t"`.

Comment: yes..because all columns come from the same alias and there is no other table involved..it should be okay not using it. it is similar to `select col1,col2 from table`